# Two Python modules require each other's contents, what is better design

Tags: python

Two Python modules requiring each other's contents seems to be a common problem that beginners face.
Many people have said: *"While this kind of setup may make intuitive sense to you now, cyclic dependencies are considered bad software engineering practice."*
Yes, it is pretty intuitive. But how can we fix it through better design, rather than using `import` instead of `from ... import`?

My example is a demo using python in Unreal Engine:

1. There are four modules: Character, Gun, Bullet and Monster
2. Character has a gun, it imports Gun, which imports Bullet
3. In Bullet, it needs to judge whether what it hit is a Monster (or a Character), so Bullet does:
   `from Monster import Monster` (it is a class)
4. The Monsters fight back of course, it needs to check whether what it hit is a Character, so Monster does:
   `from Character import Character`

Character and Monster import each other.

Comment: Is it really important what is getting hit? have `Character` and `Monster` derived from a base class and use it instead of the specific classes.

Comment: Why is it bullet's and monster's responsibility to judge what it hit? I would have some `HitJudge` that would import Character, Bullet, Monster and it would orchestrate what hit what

Comment: It is really import  to konw what is getting hit, cause we don‘t want to hurt your mate which is a Character too. Character and Monster don't  derive from base class.

Comment: Why is it bullet's and monster's responsibility to judge what it hit? Cause bullet has a sphere collison component which is responsible for collision detection.  And also there is a sphere collison component on Monster's  claw. We will bind a handler for hit event from sphere. The handler will get what it hit which is a parent class object called UActor.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking: Decomposition is what you are looking for.

Instead of monsters hitting characters or
monsters hitting monsters or
characters hitting characters or
characters hitting monsters
... you want to recognize that this can be simplified or extracted:

Given you have this scenario now:

```
   [module]
   Character{
     Shoot() {
       self.pistol.Attack(x,y,z, ...)
     }
   }

   [module]
   Monster{
     Attack() {
       self.swingArm(a,b,c, ...)
     }
   }
```

Depending on how you detect hits the following may or may not be relevant:

This is one way to solve your problem or to reorganize your code

```
   [module]               [module]
   Character{             Attack{
     OnHit()  <---------    event-emitter
     Attack() .........|>  attack logic                   
   }

   [module]
    Monster{
     OnHit() <----------   event-emitter
     SwingArm() .......|>  melee attack logic
                          }
    }
```

- `<---------` is a message
- `.......|>` is code composition
  (you import something and stick it in a property of your class)

This is a simplification of everything you would have to do, but it hopefully gives you an idea: identify common behavior and move it to a third module.